# Backbone - IE10 page everytime scrolls to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, internet-explorer-9

I have such div inside the page

```
<div class="test">Click here</div>
```

and event on it

```
events: {
    'click .test': 'myFunc',
},
```

It opens dialog window, but under Internet Explorer v9 and v10, page scrolls to the top. I was unable to track the issue after debugging it.

I also tried a hack to scroll to the link at the moment of click, here is the code:

```
var x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollLeft,
    y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;
```

This also did not work.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

the problem is not in Backbone, problem is in extended jQuery focus function. Please take a look:

```
var originalFocus = $.fn.focus;
$.fn.focus = function () {
    if (this.hasClass('no-scroll')) {
        var x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollLeft,
            y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;

        originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
        window.scrollTo(x, y);

    } else {
        return originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

in another browsers it works great, but not in IE, seems that after apply IE do not get to scrollTo..

Comment: What scrolls to the top? What are you using for a dialog window? Do you have a jsbin/fiddle to demonostrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a simpler issue then you'd expect. If the code you posted above is everything, then there's one issue I can point to.

In your events object, you cannot have a comma after a line if nothing proceeds after it. So removing the extra commas,

```
events: {
    'click .test': 'myFunc'
}
```

Again, you might have subtracted code so my point is void, but it's always safe to suggest these things!